# Windows 7 Phone button with multiple textblocks

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have created a button in Blend by editing it's style.  I added multiple text blocks with the intention of displaying data to the user in real time.  However, I don't know how to interface with those text blocks in my code behind.

My Style XAML is this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="8,12,12,12">
                                <TextBlock Margin="121,5,98,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Current Program:" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock Margin="92,68,80,81" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" RenderTransformOrigin="0.265,0.51" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="271" x:Name="programName"/>
                            <TextBlock Height="32" Margin="21,0,16,12" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Date:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="CurrentDate"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```

My code to display the button is this:

```
    <Grid x:Name="middleRow" Grid.Row="2">
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="8,8,0,8" Style="{StaticResource ButtonCenter}" x:Name="Current" Click="Current_Click" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" />
    </Grid>
```

In my code behind after the InitializeComponent(); I would like to change the ProgramName text block and the CurrentDate text block.

I'm thinking that I might have to create a control to do this but I'm not sure.  My attempts at doing so failed (misc. errors).  Can I access these text blocks in code?  Please let me know.

UPDATE:

I wound up doing it like this:

```
<Button Margin="8,8,0,8" x:Name="Current" Click="Current_Click">  
    <Button.Content>  
        <StackPanel>  
            <TextBlock x:Name="ProgramName" Text="program name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />  
            <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentDate" Text="current date" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />  
        </StackPanel>  
    </Button.Content>  
</Button>
```

I applied my styles from the template in Blend and it appears to be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference controls in a style by name as there could be multiple copies of them on a page.

If you made your button into a custom control you could make the text for the ProgramTitle and CurrentDate properties (which woudl be very easy to set).

Alternatively you could use databinding to set these values.